# Is there any way to create variables for movieclips in main timeline? AS3

Tags: variables, actionscript-3, parent-child

if I declare

```
var myclip:Movieclip = new SomeSymbol();
```

is there any way I can declare a variable for this clip in the main timeline?
Obviously I can do it in the symbol timeline but would be great if I could just declare it in the timeline so I can have all these variables in one place instead of going through hundreds of symbols in the library.

maybe something like

```
var myclip.myvar:Number = 0;
```

obviously this doesnt work but is an example to give you an idea of what I'm asking

Comment: Just **myclip.myvar = 0;** is enough to attach a new field/member to **myclip**. However, you cannot **declare** variables elsewhere, that is the point of OOP.

Comment: MovieClip is a `dynamic` class type so you are able to write values to it during run-time by using `myclip.myvar = 0` and then accessing the value with `myclip.myvar`. You don't define instance variables outside class types, repeating Organis, it's not how OOP operates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Symbol in the editor then move to the Library to Create a Class for it .

Class should look like this :

```
package {

public class SomeSymbol{
    
    
    public var myVar:*;
    
    public function SomeSymbol() {
    
    }
}
}
```

[image: This is an example of it]

When you create class , add whatever variables you want then you can access them easy by :
var myclip:SomeSymbol = new SomeSymbol();
trace(myclip.myVar);